# Delphi RESTRequest - Unable to get authorization?

Tags: rest, delphi

I would like to GET information from our Freshdesk page using a TRESTRequest component but am unable to get authorization. I am however able to get authorization when I send the request using Postman.

I've tried every solution I can find in forums but I repeatedly get an error...

```
{
    "code": "invalid_credentials",
    "message": "You have to be logged in to perform this action."
}
```

This is what I'm using to create the request using Delphi 11...

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RESTClient1.BaseURL := 'https://bentley.freshdesk.com/api/v2/';

  RESTRequest1.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmGET;
  RESTRequest1.Resource := 'solutions/categories';

  RESTRequest1.Params.Clear;
  with RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem do
    begin
        ContentType := ctAPPLICATION_JSON;
        name        := 'Authorization';
        Value       := 'Basic ' + edtApiKey ;
        Kind        :=  pkHTTPHEADER;
    end;

  RESTRequest1.Execute;
end;
```

The *edtApiKey* is an edit box wherein the already Base64 encoded API key is typed.

The thing is, I can put the exact same information (URI and Authorization header) into Postman and the request returns as expected with full authorization...?

There must be some difference in syntax between what postman sends out and what delphi sends but I, for the life of me, can't figure it out.

Comment: Setting a ContentType for the parameter used for the Authorization header seems wrong but probably gets ignored when creating the request.

Comment: Yeah, I could see that. I just tried commenting it out but made no difference in the result. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I make a habit of testing with Delphi's Rest Debugger first.  When adding parameters to the debugger, you have a choice to encode or not. Much faster that trying code first.  Just a suggestion..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `poDoNotEncode` option to the parameter:

```
  with RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem do
    begin
        ContentType := ctAPPLICATION_JSON;
        name        := 'Authorization';
        Value       := 'Basic ' + edtApiKey ;
        Kind        :=  pkHTTPHEADER;
        Option      := [doNotEncode];
    end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to supply a dummy password. The docs use `X` so add `:X` to the API Key before it is Base64 encoded but any password will do apparently.

Excepts from [FRESHDESK API REFERENCE : Authentication](https://developers.freshdesk.com/api/#authentication)

> You can use your personal API key to authenticate the request. If you
> use the API key, there is no need for a password. You can use any set
> of characters as a dummy password.

> Note: If you are sure that your credentials are correct, but are still
> unable to access your helpdesk, make sure that the "APIkey:X" is
> Base64-encoded before passing it as an "Authorization" header.

Comment: That's a good catch, I was only Base 64 encoding the api key, not with a ':X' on the end. I just tried that and it wasn't the magic sauce :( Same 401 unauthorized error. It works either way when entered into Postman though apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not that you need to use edtApiKey.Text (string) instead of edtApiKey (object)?